# OC4J problem with ssl (secure-web-site.xml)

Tags: java, web-applications, ssl, oc4j

I'm working on eclipse and after making some changes in application and redeploying EAR file on OC4J server (i've added ssl support)  my application binding in secure-web-site.xml ( i mean:  tag) disappears or rather is not adding. What do i have to do to get this done automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done this steps?:

config/secure-web-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-site xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/web-site-10_0.xsd"
    port="9880"
    secure="true"
    log-request-info="true"
    display-name="Oracle iAS Containers for J2EE HTTPS Web Site" 
    schema-major-version="10" 
    schema-minor-version="0"> 

    <default-web-app application="default" name="defaultWebApp" />
    <access-log path="../log/secure-web-access.log" format="$ip [$time] '$request' $status $size" />
    <ssl-config factory="com.evermind.ssl.JSSESSLServerSocketFactory"
        keystore="/jdk1.5.0_05/jre/lib/security/cacerts" 
        keystore-password="changeit" truststore-password="">
        <property name="provider" 
            value="com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider"/>
    </ssl-config>
</web-site>
```

Deploy the application (app.ear):

```
java -jar admin_client.jar deployer:oc4j:localhost oc4jadmin adminpass -deploy -file app.ear -deploymentName app
```

Bind it to secure-web-site:

```
java -jar admin_client.jar deployer:oc4j:localhost oc4jadmin adminpass -bindWebApp -appName app -webModuleName app -webSiteName secure-web-site -contextRoot /app
```